# Odoo 16 / custom website : Pagination returns all data after clicking any page number in pagination result

Tags: xml, web, controller, odoo-16

I paginated the search result(input text and search button) . For the first, query set gives me perfect result , but when I clicked on any page number from pagination, it accepts search key as null and get all data from db. here is the code:

The result template with pagination

```
<template id="result" name="Result">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <div id="wrap">
                <div class="oe_structure"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <t t-call="my_module.search"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="block-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-2">
                                <h2>
                                    <span class="heading-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="hidden-sm-down">Result</span>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                         
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                               
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <t t-foreach="partners" t-as="item">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <t t-esc="item.name"/>
                                    </td>
                                   
                                </tr>
                            </t>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <nav aria-label="..." t-if="pager" class="mt-5">
                        <ul t-if="pager['page_count'] > 1"
                        t-attf-class="#{ classname or '' } pagination m-0 #{_classes}" t-att-style="style or None">
                        <li t-attf-class="page-item #{'disabled' if pager['page']['num'] == 1 else ''}">
                            <a t-att-href=" pager['page_previous']['url'] if pager['page']['num'] != 1 else None"
                               t-attf-class="page-link #{extraLinkClass}">
                                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left" role="img" aria-label="Previous" title="Previous"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <t t-foreach="pager['pages']" t-as="page">
                            <li t-attf-class="page-item #{'active' if page['num'] == pager['page']['num'] else ''}">
                                <a t-att-href="page['url']" t-attf-class="page-link #{extraLinkClass}"
                                   t-out="page['num']"/>
                            </li>
                        </t>
                        <li t-attf-class="page-item #{'disabled' if pager['page']['num'] == pager['page_count'] else ''}">
                            <a t-att-href="pager['page_next']['url'] if pager['page']['num'] != pager['page_count'] else None"
                               t-attf-class="page-link #{extraLinkClass}">
                                <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" role="img" aria-label="Next" title="Next"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
```

The search temple :

```
<template id="search">
        <div class="float-center" style="text-align: center;">
            <form action="/page/result" method="post" class="form-inline align-items-center" style="margin-top: 4%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="name" name="name"
                               placeholder="Name"/>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">search</button>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-2">
                        <h5>
                            <span class="hidden-sm-down">
                                <t t-esc="search"/>
                            </span>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </template>
```

The controller :

```
  PPG = 20

   @http.route(['/page/result', '/page/result/<int:page>'], type='http', auth="user",
                website=True)
    def result_partners_pages(self, page=0, search='', sortby=None, domain=[], ppg=False, **post):
        if ppg:
            try:
                ppg = int(ppg)
            except ValueError:
                ppg = PPG
            post["ppg"] = ppg
        else:
            ppg = PPG
        domain = [('is_company', '=', True)]
        name = post.get('name', '')
        domain += [('name', '=ilike', '%' + name + '%')]

        sortings = {
            'name': {'label': _('Name'), 'order': 'name'},
        }
        partners = request.env['res.partner'].sudo().search(domain)
        product_count = len(partners)
        pager = request.website.pager(url='/page/result', total=product_count, page=page, step=ppg, scope=7,
                                      url_args={'sortby': sortby})

        partners = partners.sudo().search(domain, limit=ppg, offset=pager['offset'])
        values = {
            'pager': pager,
            'partners': partners,
            'sortings': sortings,
            'sortby': sortby,
            'default_url': '/page/result',
            'post': post,
        }
        return request.render("my_module.result", values)
```

Any help please ?
Thanks.